# ADODB.Stream Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

Tags: vbscript, stream, ado

I want if `text = ""` create new file with contents = userval, but if `Len(text) > 0` then I want find existing file and change in them this text so if not exist so add text and userval to existing content.

```
Public Property Let val(text,userval)
  'on error resume next
  Dim strText, strResult, strChange
  If Len(text) >0 then
    strChange = False

    stream.open
    stream.loadfromfile strAbsFile
    strT = stream.readtext
    splArr = split(strText,"^")
    on error resume next
    For i = 0 to Ubound(splArr)
      splArrFields = split(splArr(i),"|") 
      If splArrFields(0) = text Then strChange = Replace(strText,splArrFields(0) & "^" & splArrFields(1),splArrFields(0) & "^" & userval)  'change value if exists
    Next
    If strChange Then strResult = strChange Else strResult = strT & "|" text & "^" & userval ' add text and value 
    stream.close
  Else
    strResult = userval
  End If
  response.write  "text" & VarType(text) & " userval" & VarType(userval) & " strResult" & VarType(strResult) ' text8 userval8 strResult8
  stream.open
  stream.writetext mycstr(strResult)
  for err11 = 0 to 50
    stream.savetofile strAbsFile, 2
    if Err.Number = 0 then exit for
    Err.Clear
  next

  stream.close
End Property
```

But I get an error:

> Error: 3001
>   Error (Hex): BB9
>   Source: ADODB.Stream
>   Description: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

I think problem Line is `stream.savetofile strAbsFile, 2`

What is wrong?

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Comment: I dont know i look in browser and dont know how debug  else

Comment: Add [error handling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184742) to all relevant statements.

Comment: In my case works only this http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14019 
.Line and .Text not work for me

Comment: I think `stream.savetofile strAbsFile, 2` this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare `Private strAbsFile` in place there you set this file path