# CSV string from GET request incomplete when storing in variable

Tags: vba, excel, csv, get

In VBA, I currently have code that returns a CSV string from the internet. However, it seems like the entire file is not being captured when I try to store it in a string variable using `.responseText`

I've heard string sizes are limited, which makes this problem understandable (I'm trying to store 1000 rows of data into a variable - which is probably not possible). I was wondering if there is a way to download the CSV file straight from the source given that I have the URL to get the response? Here is the relevant code that I have:

```
              Dim JiraReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60    
              With JiraReq
                  ' Create Session
                 downloadUrl = https://myurlishere.atlassian.net 
                 ' This is not the actual form of the URL, but it does 
                  ' successfully grab the CSV string (but the string variable 
                  ' will not store all of it - probably because of the size)
                 .Open "GET", downloadUrl, False
                 .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeBase64(username + ":" + password)
                 .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
                 .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
                 .send
               End With

                CSVData = JiraReq.responseText
                If JiraReq.Status = 200 Then
                    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
                    oStream.Open
                    oStream.Type = 1
                    oStream.Write JiraReq.responseText
                    Filename = "C:\file" & i & ".csv"
                    oStream.SaveToFile Filename, 2
                    oStream.Close
                End If
```

For reference, I have looked at the following links to try to solve this issue:

[Arguments out of acceptable range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243569/adodb-stream-arguments-are-of-the-wrong-type-are-out-of-acceptable-range-or-ar)

[Downloading file from web with VBA](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29063390/VBA-to-download-file-from-web.html)

[HTTP response text returning incomplete Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042430/http-response-text-fetching-incomplete-html)

Comment: import urldownloadtofile maybe.

Comment: *I've heard string sizes are limited* - In VBA the limit is ~2GB so that's not likely going to be the issue, similarly there is no specified limit on .responseText

Comment: Would it be possible that the website I am using would only return part of the response @Alex K. ?

Comment: I've seen websites download more of the page as you scroll down.. maybe this is (not) happening here.

Comment: @Jeeped would something like the post from donato in [this post](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?33145-Download-from-Excel-via-URLDownloadToFile) work like you are saying with `urldownloadtofile`?

Comment: Are you asking me to test code from vbaexpress?

Comment: urldownloadtofile cannot be used with authentication header afaik

Comment: If you install Fiddler & run the request you will be able to see what the server is responding with in a raw form to see if its what you expect.

Comment: The URL I am requesting responds by downloading a CSV file if used from a normal browser. Is there a way to just automate the process of downloading from the browser and then download the file as a certain name like "Jira1.csv"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code ended up looking like this:

```
    For i = 1 To pageCount Step 1
        ' MsgBox "Entering For Loop"
        Dim startNumber As Integer
        startNumber = (i - 1) * 1000

        Dim downloadUrl As String
        downloadUrl = "https://myurl.atlassian.net/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-csv-current-fields/" & CStr(filterID) & "/SearchRequest-" & CStr(filterID) & ".csv?tempMax=1000&pager/start=" & CStr(startNumber)

        With JiraReq
          ' Create Session
         Debug.Print "Getting page " & CStr(i) & " of " & CStr(pageCount)
         .Open "GET", downloadUrl, False
         .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeBase64(username + ":" + password)
         .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
         .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
         .send
       End With

       file_name = "C:\VBA\file" & i & ".csv"
       If JiraReq.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write JiraReq.responseBody
            oStream.SaveToFile file_name, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            oStream.Close
       End If
```

I had to change from `.responseText` to `.responseBody`.